# Get rightmost non-zero value position for each row in dataframe (non lambda method)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large data frame and I need to get the last zero value index for each row in it if there are zeros from the right.

If there is not a zero in the row I need the last index.

Working code below. with correct output.

Is there a way to vectorize this code (not use a lambda)

Example Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'a': {0: 14, 1: 0, 2: 105, 3: 67},
     'b': {0: 67, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 63},
     'c': {0: 35, 1: 0, 2: 530, 3: 431},
     'd': {0: 500, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 500},
     'e': {0: 13, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 12},
     'f': {0: 123, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}}
)

# if row has no zeros use last index
def func(row):
    # if row is all zeros return first index
    if sum(row == 0) == len(row):
        return row.index[0]

    # if row is all non zero return last index
    if sum(row != 0)== len(row):
        return row.index[-1]

    # else return index of right most non zero value
    return row.loc[row != 0].index[-1]

df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    f
1    a
2    c
3    e
```

Comment: I will fix issue in question wording... desired output is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find where it's not equal to 0, cumsum and then find the first instance where this is the maximum.

```
df.ne(0).cumsum(1).idxmax(1)

0    f
1    a
2    c
3    e
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is the correct solution if the index is resorted

Comment: Why do you need the `[::-1]`+`sort_index` ? Just `df.ne(0).cumsum(1).idxmax(1)` seems fine

Comment: @RafaelC Wow, yeah literally not doing what I thought I was. Fixed it. Spaced out there.